# plot graphs in R while showing all the x axis values

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to plot a graph with my data.
My code for that is

```
plot(birthRate$country_code, birthRate$yr2014, main = "Birth Rate by Countries 2014")
```

My out put is like this:[image: Birth Rate by Countries 2014 picture]

But I want to show all values in x axis.

dput(birthRate):

```
    structure(list(series_code = structure(c(21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
    21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
    21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L), .Label = c("NY.GNP.PCAP.CD", 
    "SE.PRM.ENRR", "SE.SEC.ENRR", "SE.TER.ENRR", "SE.TER.ENRR.FE", 
    "SH.ALC.PCAP.LI", "SH.DTH.COMM.ZS", "SH.DTH.INJR.ZS", "SH.DTH.NCOM.ZS", 
    "SH.IMM.IBCG", "SH.STA.MMRT.NE", "SH.STA.TRAF.P5", "SH.XPD.PCAP", 
    "SH.XPD.PRIV.ZS", "SH.XPD.PUBL.ZS", "SH.XPD.TOTL.ZS", "SL.UEM.TOTL.FE.ZS", 
    "SL.UEM.TOTL.MA.ZS", "SL.UEM.TOTL.ZS", "SP.ADO.TFRT", "SP.DYN.CBRT.IN", 
    "SP.DYN.CDRT.IN", "SP.DYN.LE00.FE.IN", "SP.DYN.LE00.IN", 
    "SP.DYN.LE00.MA.IN", 
    "SP.DYN.TFRT.IN"), class = "factor"), country_name = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 
    19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 28L, 29L), .Label = c("Australia", 
    "Brunei Darussalam", "Cambodia", "China", "Fiji", "Indonesia", 
    "Japan", "Kiribati", "Korea, Dem. People’s Rep.", "Korea, Rep.", 
    "Lao PDR", "Malaysia", "Marshall Islands", "Micronesia, Fed. Sts.", 
    "Mongolia", "Nauru", "New Zealand", "Palau", "Papua New Guinea", 
    "Philippines", "Samoa", "Singapore", "Solomon Islands", "Thailand", 
    "Timor-Leste", "Tonga", "Tuvalu", "Vanuatu", "Vietnam"), class = "factor"), 
    country_code = structure(c(1L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 
    20L, 10L, 11L, 14L, 5L, 13L, 16L, 19L, 17L, 29L, 21L, 22L, 
    23L, 24L, 25L, 28L, 27L), .Label = c("AUS", "BRN", "CHN", 
    "FJI", "FSM", "IDN", "JPN", "KHM", "KIR", "KOR", "LAO", "MHL", 
    "MNG", "MYS", "NRU", "NZL", "PHL", "PLW", "PNG", "PRK", "SGP", 
    "SLB", "THA", "TLS", "TON", "TUV", "VNM", "VUT", "WSM"), class = "factor"), 
    yr2001 = c(12.7, 20.913, 27.327, 13.38, 24.41, 21.486, 9.3, 
    30.228, 17.414, 11.6, 30.999, 21.445, 29.21, 19.035, 14.36, 
    34.396, 29.301, 30.269, 11.8, 35.403, 14.025, 41.441, 28.365, 
    31.84, 17.13), yr2002 = c(12.8, 20.137, 26.793, 12.86, 24.103, 
    21.49, 9.3, 29.965, 16.92, 10.2, 30.287, 20.39, 28.453, 19.001, 
    13.67, 33.95, 28.892, 29.991, 11.4, 35.226, 13.653, 40.428, 
    28.468, 31.219, 16.921), yr2003 = c(12.6, 19.522, 26.44, 
    12.41, 23.804, 21.5, 9.2, 29.775, 16.431, 10.2, 29.753, 19.435, 
    27.669, 19.209, 13.94, 33.49, 28.404, 29.778, 10.5, 35.061, 
    13.32, 39.726, 28.565, 30.597, 16.839), yr2004 = c(12.3, 
    19.065, 26.24, 12.29, 23.508, 21.499, 8.6936, 29.647, 15.961, 
    9.8, 29.38, 18.62, 26.886, 19.627, 14.2, 33.03, 27.845, 29.624, 
    10.3, 34.889, 13.025, 39.368, 28.624, 29.993, 16.848), yr2005 = c(12.8, 
    18.738, 26.145, 12.4, 23.208, 21.476, 8.4133, 29.572, 15.532, 
    8.9, 29.134, 17.971, 26.139, 20.223, 13.96, 32.575, 27.238, 
    29.499, 10.2, 34.68, 12.764, 39.326, 28.611, 29.427, 16.919
    ), yr2006 = c(12.9, 18.499, 26.098, 12.09, 22.901, 21.429, 
    8.65, 29.537, 15.166, 9.2, 28.966, 17.498, 25.461, 20.959, 
    14.14, 32.121, 26.619, 29.355, 10.3, 34.409, 12.533, 39.509, 
    28.499, 28.92, 17.03), yr2007 = c(14.1, 18.292, 26.043, 12.1, 
    22.586, 21.364, 8.63, 29.528, 14.87, 10, 28.821, 17.171, 
    24.872, 21.769, 15.15, 31.659, 26.025, 29.148, 10, 34.063, 
    12.323, 39.752, 28.288, 28.475, 17.163), yr2008 = c(14, 18.07, 
    25.937, 12.14, 22.263, 21.283, 8.7, 29.526, 14.648, 9.4, 
    28.651, 16.954, 24.385, 22.576, 15.1, 31.186, 25.489, 28.845, 
    10.2, 33.637, 12.123, 39.92, 27.982, 28.091, 17.298), yr2009 = c(13.9, 
    17.809, 25.755, 12.13, 21.929, 21.177, 8.5, 29.513, 14.498, 
    9, 28.429, 16.828, 24.011, 23.311, 14.53, 30.706, 25.023, 
    28.442, 9.9, 33.132, 11.927, 39.95, 27.588, 27.766, 17.409
    ), yr2010 = c(13.7, 17.499, 25.491, 11.9, 21.583, 21.034, 
    8.5, 29.468, 14.411, 9.4, 28.142, 16.773, 23.751, 23.892, 
    14.68, 30.229, 24.634, 27.944, 9.3, 32.555, 11.725, 39.8, 
    27.112, 27.486, 17.473), yr2011 = c(13.6, 17.146, 25.164, 
    11.93, 21.221, 20.841, 8.3, 29.377, 14.374, 9.4, 27.8, 16.765, 
    23.598, 24.252, 14, 29.764, 24.315, 27.372, 9.5, 31.918, 
    11.51, 39.461, 26.57, 27.236, 17.477), yr2012 = c(13.7, 16.774, 
    24.812, 12.1, 20.846, 20.595, 8.2, 29.235, 14.363, 9.6, 27.43, 
    16.783, 23.528, 24.378, 13.87, 29.318, 24.041, 26.768, 10.1, 
    31.25, 11.281, 38.985, 25.992, 26.993, 17.424), yr2013 = c(13.3, 
    16.405, 24.462, 12.08, 20.463, 20.297, 8.2, 29.044, 14.358, 
    8.6, 27.051, 16.805, 23.511, 24.275, 13.2, 28.899, 23.79, 
    26.172, 9.3, 30.578, 11.041, 38.419, 25.409, 26.739, 17.318
    ), yr2014 = c(12.9, 16.043, 24.119, 12.4, 20.075, 19.955, 
    8, 28.8, 14.349, 8.6, 26.666, 16.811, 23.531, 23.949, 12.68, 
    28.51, 23.552, 25.608, 9.8, 29.921, 10.79, 37.783, 24.846, 
    26.466, 17.157)), .Names = c("series_code", "country_name", 
    "country_code", "yr2001", "yr2002", "yr2003", "yr2004", "yr2005", 
    "yr2006", "yr2007", "yr2008", "yr2009", "yr2010", "yr2011", "yr2012", 
    "yr2013", "yr2014"), row.names = c(30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
    36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 43L, 44L, 46L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 
    52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 57L, 58L), class = "data.frame", na.action = 
    structure(c(13L, 16L, 18L, 27L), .Names = c("42", "45", "47", "56"), class = "omit"))
```

Comment: Can you provide the output from `dput(birthRate)` so we can have a reproducible example to work with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try plotting the x-axis labels horizontally.

Try this out:
`plot(birthRate$country_code, birthRate$yr2014, main = "Birth Rate by Countries 2014", las=2)`

**Edit:**

I was able to make this barplot using `ggplot2`. 
[image]

Here's my code:

```
birthRate <- arrange(birthRate, yr2014)
p <- ggplot(birthRate, aes(y=yr2014, x=reorder(country_code, yr2014), fill=country_code)) + 
    geom_col()
p
```

**Note**: Your `dput()` output has 29 observations for the `country_code` variable, but only 25 for the `yr2014` variable. I didn't know exactly where the missing data was, so I just removed the last four observations from the `country_code` variable to get things to line up. Your output may look slightly different based on where the `NAs` are...

I hope this was helpful!

Comment: Glad to hear it! You can try changing the font size of the axis labels using the cex.lab argument if this doesn't always work. For example, cex.lab = 0.75 would plot axis labels that are only 75% of their original size.

Comment: also, wondering if there is a way to show those variables as bars? as its hard to see the value for each variables. just couldn't figure out a graph. "barplot" command also didnt work for my dataset

Comment: I'd look into using ggplot2's geom_bar() function. I'm stuck on mobile right now, but I'll try and create some example code for you once I'm at my laptop.

Comment: tried like:     >g = ggplot(df, aes(birthRate$country_name))    > g = g + geom_line(aes(y=birthRate$yr2014), colour="red")    >g    but it gives me this error message   > Error in if (is.waive(data) || empty(data)) return(cbind(data, PANEL = integer(0))) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: Could you paste the output of `dput(birthRate)` in your example so I can play around with your data? After brushing up with ggplot2 from [this](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html) tutorial, I realized that `geom_col()` would suit you better than `geom_bar()`. Without seeing your data, my first attempt would look something like this: `g <- ggplot(birthRate, aes(y=yr2014, x=country_code, fill=country_code) + geom_col()`. If you wanted the bargraph to be in order from lowest to highest birthrate, you could use `library(dplyr)` and `birthRate2 <-
 arrange(birthRate, yr2014)`.